# AWS IoT Policy overly permissive

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to make an AWS IoT Policy for a Cognito Identity to be able to communicate with a AWS IoT Thing. However, the policy is overly permissive according to the AWS IoT Audit check: "Policy allows broad access to IoT data plane actions: [iot:Subscribe, iot:Connect, iot:Publish]." How can I fix this?

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Connect",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:<aws account id>:client/${iot:ClientId}"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:<aws account id>:topic/$aws/things/*/shadow/get"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Subscribe"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:<aws account id>:topicfilter/$aws/events/presence/connected/*",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:<aws account id>:topicfilter/$aws/events/presence/disconnected/*",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:<aws account id>:topicfilter/$aws/things/*/shadow/update/accepted",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:<aws account id>:topicfilter/$aws/things/*/shadow/get/accepted"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Receive"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:<aws account id>:topic/$aws/things/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that you are trying an overexposed policy , since you have not mentioned the exact usecase i suppose that this policy is the least privileged policy i.e. the use case does not allow your policy to be more restrictive if that is not the case please restrict your policy to something like :

arn:aws:iot:region:account-id:client/*
to
arn:aws:iot:region:account-id:client/${iot:ClientId}

where iot:ClientId is a policy variable and refers to the clientId of the mqtt connection
Also please refer

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/audit-chk-iot-policy-permissive.html

Comment: I still get an uncompliant error for connect, publish, and subscribe. My use case is for a mobile user to connect to a device and control it.

Comment: Can you please share your new policy

Comment: I've updated the original post. I only made the change you suggested.

Comment: i can see that you have only made changes to the connect , you need to remove "*" from other places as well and make policy restrictive to that deice e.g recieve is still using a wildcard

Comment: What do I replace the * with?